# main has no run member

Tags: python

I have the following structure in code.

In `main.py`:

```
def run(parameters):
    # do something
```

In `execution.py`:

```
import main
if __name__ = "main":
    main.run(parameters)
```

However, I get the following error - main has no 'run' member.

Comment: Looking at the code you pasted here I was expecting python to throw up a different error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run that code there is no output, because the test in `execution.py` should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`. The `if`-test in your code is never true.

Buy when I fix that problem, `main.run()` executes as expected, but only if I fix another problem. The function body of `run()` must consist of more than a comment. You need `pass` at the very least.

So that is a syntax error, which means that the `def` statement doesn't actually define the function. Which explains the message.

Comment: Is `main.py` *exactly* as you posted it, or is there a typo there too? If it is exactly as you posted it, your `execution.py` will fail at `import main` with a syntax error.